# Repeating function recursive in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a function that outputs `char*m` `n` times, as such as the expected output would be `["ccc","ccc"]` for the input `2 3 c`. Here is what i have so far:

```
rectangle :: Int -> Int -> Char -> [string]
rectangle n m c 
    | m > 0 = [concat ([[c]] ++ (rectangle n (m-1) c))] 
    | otherwise = []
```

I am able to carry out the first part, `char*m`, so it returns `["ccc"]`. Thing is: I also would like to be able to repeat my string `n` times.

I have tried using replicate but it doesn't seem to work, yet it works if doing it in the console: `replicate 2 (rectangle 2 3 c)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addendum to Refactor's answer, I think his approach is the correct one. He subdivides the problem until it can be solved trivially using built-in functions. If you want to roll your own solution for learning purposes, I suggest you keep this subdivision, and go from there, implementing your own replicate. Otherwise, you will end up with a single function which does too much.

So the remaining problem is that of implementing replicate. My first idea would be to look at the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#replicate) for replicate. I found it via [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), which led me to [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3areplicate), which has links to the source code. Excerpted from the source:

```
replicate               :: Int -> a -> [a]
replicate n x           =  take n (repeat x)
```

which is nice and concise, again using the built-in functions. If you want to completely roll your own replicate, you can do:

```
myReplicate                 :: Int -> a -> [a]
myReplicate n x | n <= 0    = []
                | otherwise = x : replicate (n-1) x
```

----------EDIT----------------

As a side note, I think your problem requires two rather orthogonal skills. The first is trying not to tackle the whole problem at once, but making some small progress instead. Then you can try to solve that smaller problem, before returning to the larger. In your case, it would likely involve recognizing that you definitely need a way of transforming the character into a series of characters of length n. Experience with functions such as map, filter, foldr and so on will help you here, since they each represent a very distinct transformation, which you might recognize.

The second skill required for your solution - if you want to roll your own - is recognizing when a function can be expressed recursively. As you can see, your problem - and indeed many common problems - can be solved without explicit recursion, but it is a nice skill to have, when the need arises. Recursive solutions do not always come easily mind, so I think the best way to gain familiarity with them are to read and practice.

For further study, I'm sure you have already been pointed to the excellent [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and [Real World Haskell](http://www.realworldhaskell.org), but just in case you haven't, here they are.

Comment: Thanks, every task i give myself i seem to fail! and most the time it can be done with simple pre-made functions, is there a set of functions that you would say one should learn and use when possible such as map, filter, replicate?

Comment: Experience with functions such as these will definitely help you. I would say that there is a core set of functions that are good to know and use. This set is fuzzy/not clearly defined, but it includes common list functions such as map, filter etc. I have expanded my answer to clarify how they can help.

Answer (score 7):

Try the replicate function this way:

```
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]

rectangle n m c = replicate n (replicate m c)
```

Also, don't forget to mention if this is homework.

Comment: The function `replicate` takes a number `n` and a value and creates a list of `n` elements of that value. So `replicate 3 'a'` yields `"aaa"`.

Comment: Thats a great easy solution, however does anyone have a solution in which it does use a pre-defined function? will help me learn :)

Comment: @Lunar A good way to learn would be to try to define `replicate` by yourself. I couldn't think of a solution, that doesn't requires the use of `replicate` somehow.

Comment: @Lunar: Do note that `replicate` is the in the standard prelude (or at least is re-exported by the prelude), but I added the type signature to help.

Comment: Would there be any performance benefit if we do something like:  let t = replicate m c in replicate n t

Comment: @Ankur: I don't think so, since Haskell uses call by need, not call by name. This means that the result of evaluated thunks are stored, so the `replicate m c` would only be evaluated once in both cases.

Comment: @Boris GHC (the standard compiler for Haskell) has a heuristic when to do CSE (common subexpression elemination) and when not. IIRC, it is roughly that expressions that do not contain any `case` expressions are CSE'd. If you want to ensure, that CSE is done, do it by hand.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I am a bit confused, I didn't think that CSE would be applicable here. Restating the question for clarification: are there potential performance benefits with `let t = replicate m c in replicate n t` over `replicate n (replicate m c)`? I thought `(replicate m c)` in the latter snippet would be passed as a thunk to `replicate n`, which would then use the thunk several times, just as `t` would be used several times in the first snippet. Then, when the whole thing is evaluated, the thunk is evaluated only once, and subsequently, its value used directly. Is this correct? cont'd...

Comment: @FUZxxl: cont'd... If so, where is the common subexpression to be eliminated?

Comment: @Boris Sorry. I was a bit tired that day. The idea of a thunk is evaluate once - use everywhere, this means, that any *value* (so anything not functionish) will be evaluated exactly once. So there is no performance benefit at all. (I'm not quite shure, but IIRC the internal representation of both ways is the same).

Comment: @FUZxxl: No problem. That was my understanding as well, glad to know it was correct. Thanks.